# Paw-App - encrypting a request field with AES

Tags: encryption, paw-app

This is a Paw question. Is there a Paw encryption add-on that supports AES working in the commonly used modes and lengths?

I have a request that includes encrypted fields. These fields are AES encrypted.  The key is 128 bits long. The encryption mode is CBC.  The encryption is performed by the mobile app.  The key is inside the mobile app.

At the moment, I capture the requests in Burp, Import them into Paw, and then I have the valid request.

I know the plaintext.  I know the key.  I know the algorithm.  I know the Initialization Vector.  There must be a better way.

I could not find anything on: https://paw.cloud/extensions/

Comment: Sorry I missed this question here. We've found workarounds for other users in order to use Crypto.JS to do encryption inside of Paw and it worked great. A previous version of Paw exposed a crypto-secure random number generator so doing crypto inside the JS sandbox of Paw is now doable in a perfectly secure manner. Though, we don't expose a high-level AES API yet. Let me know if you need it still and we can post something about it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MichaMazaheri, I certainly would like it.  AES with Cipher-Block-Chaining mode and support for Key length of 128 or 256 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two new **DynamicValues** that should allow you to do what you wish to do:

- AES Decrypt
- AES Encrypt

They are based on an npm port of the [**CryptoJS**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) library and should expose most of the API for decryption/encryption in AES.

Here's a couple screenshot to show you what it looks like:

[image: AES Encryption example]
[image: AES Decryption example]

Since the DynamicValues are quite recent, there may be a few issues with them. Don't hesitate to report them.

Comment: The encryption key I used was encoded in UTF16-littleEndian before use.  This did not appear supported in the new Paw extension but I imagine you have a solved a problem for a lot of people.